# import issue in mariadb database while importing wordpress data in linux terminal

Tags: database, wordpress, mariadb, importerror

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1862820: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''[event_count]         \n                       <a href="#reguser" role="button">\n                         <svg aria-hid...' at line 2

Comment: How was the dump made (and from what MariaDB version)? How is the import made (and to what MariaDB version)?. What is the rest of the context on line 1862820?

Comment: I was using line --default-character-set=utf8 while importing mariadb database. I have used latest version

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I didn't ask 4 clarifying questions so that one could be answered vaguely. They weren't rhetorical. Please answer them by editing the question.